# Encrypted backups created on Android 4.3 cannot be restored on 4.4

Tags: android, android-backup-service

Problem to restoring Backup

1. Create an encrypted backup on 4.3 with `adb backup` (specify password)
2. Try to restore on 4.4
3. Restore silently fails.

Show me below error:

Password is considered incorrect, even though it is:

```
W/BackupManagerService(774): Incorrect password
```

W/BackupManagerService(774): Invalid restore data; aborting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by recent changes to the [SecretKeyFactory](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/12/changes-to-secretkeyfactory-api-in.html). If a password contains a non ASCII character, then the password set in 4.3 will not be valid in 4.4. I believe Google is already aware of the issue.

You can try to use an open source [Android-Backup-Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) to repack your backup with a new password or wait until Google fixes the issue.